# Understanding OPT Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Okay, i am trying to understand OPT algorithm then it will make it easy for me to code it.
I cant follow along with the slide and its making no sense. Can someone walk me through it step by step on how to do it?

This looks identical to the LRU algorithm. Do we keep a second array with a counter?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently must know in advance which pages are going to be used and in what order; this is the list `1, 2, 3, ..., 4, 5` in your example. When you must replace a page, you choose the frame containing the page that will be used last amongst all of them.

In this example, you access pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, and 2 without any page faults (since all pages are currently swapped in).

Your next page access, page 5, is not in any frame, so you must choose a frame to put it into. Based on upcoming page hits (1, 2, 3, 4), page 4 (in frame 4) will be last to be accessed, so you swap page 5 into frame 4 (as shown in your diagram).

The next pages, 1, 2, and 3 are accessed without any fault.

Now page 4 is accessed but it was previously swapped out so you have a page fault. Your list of upcoming accesses shows only page 5 will be needed, so any of 1, 2, and 3 may be swapped out. 1 was chosen, presumably because it is first.

Answer (score 0):

An optimal algorithm is just an algorithm that results in the theoretically fewest cache misses.

In other words, it's impossible to know the optimum until *after* you have how the cache would have been used.  That means you cannot *code* an algorithm ahead of time that is optimal; because, you don't know how the cache will actually be used.

Optimal algorithms are very useful as a baseline against *actual* algorithms.  Every non-trivial caching problem will eventually cache-miss.  Knowing the "absolute minimum" number of misses for a particular run can provide a baseline for comparing two caching algorithms.

For example, if you *must* miss the cache four times, then an algorithm that misses the cache six times looks pretty good in comparison to an algorithm that misses the cache seven times.  If you must miss the cache 1000 times, then an algorithm that misses the cache 1006 times and one that misses the cache 1007 times are nearly equivalent.

Some algorithms hit the cache more often than others based on the usage pattern of the cache.  One example is LRU, which will drop seldom used items from the cache: it is good if you tend to do multiple accesses of the same items during some small period of time.  On the other hand, if you need to access each item many times, but once in order (as in a loop), then LRU can have horrible performance (~100% cache miss) because each access only kicks an item out of the cache.  Coincidentally, a MRU (where new items replace the most recently used) cache will perform better than LRU under these conditions, because at least the cache hits once for the first few items.